# Where is the story of Draupadi and her five husbands written in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, draupadi

Where is the story of Draupadi and her five husbands written in the sanskrit version of Mahabharata? Can you give me the chapter, or paragraph?

What does the following picture depict in the story?

[image]

Comment: You mean in which part they married?

Comment: @Bingming, Yes.

Comment: Check Swayamvara Parva and Vaivāhika Parva, they discuss the whole process. Both these are sub-parvas in Ādi Parva. 
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc4193.html
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc4262.html

Comment: @Bingming, I need citation from Sanskrit version.

Comment: The same sub-parvas are within the Sanskrit version as well, just the chapter numbers can be but here and there. 
Chapter 187, Ādi Parva,  onwards in Sanskrit version
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mahabharata-sanskrit/d/doc971400.html
Actually chapter 186 onwards, that is the point when Pāṇḍavas start going towards Pāñcāla